# How do I reset my sensor to track Shrines?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I set my sensor to track the location of an item from the Hyrule Compendium. How do I reset it to start tracking Shrines again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Purah pad map, press Y and you should be able to reset the sensor to track shrines again.

[image]